# Publishing a work which is not related to the work done in the company

Tags: publications, research-process, industry, independent-researcher

I am working in a company after completing my PhD. When I get time, I carry out some research work related to my PhD work but not related to what I do in the company. I look forward to publish the work in journals/conferences as an independent author. I guess I should use the present affiliation in the article. Will this affect the chances of getting the article published?

Answer (score 2):

I used "Independent Researcher" and personal email address two times for my papers: published at good venues without any affiliation-related problems.

And depending on your local laws, the company policies, nature of your research, how you conducted it (normal working hours or weekends, use of company equipment) you may not own the research results and may need to work with the company on publishing it using the company's affiliation.

Comment: Agree, I see no issue in terms of the publisher, but the thing to watch is corporate policies. At the least they may require a formal release from the company. Or they may waive it and say it is unrelated and you should ignore them. But you need to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I also work in a company(have a PhD too). My company strictly rules that any invention, discovery that I have done whilst in the company becomes a shared intellectual property with the company. I think you should talk with your immediate work supervisor or Intellectual property department(if you have one) before you embark on publishing your work.
As for the possibility for the paper being published, I personally think journal articles are published based on their originality and degree of importance. Your current affiliation could be slightly helpful but I think there are a host of factors that determine the final conclusion, i.e, publication of the article.